# ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 1 and 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I was hoping someone might be able to assist with this.  I have the following placeholder:

```
self.actions = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, ], 'action')
```

I then assign a_indices (used elsewhere in code):

```
a_indices = tf.stack([tf.range(tf.shape(self.actions)[0], dtype=tf.int32), self.actions], axis=1)
```

However, not specifying the second tensor dimension in the placeholder causes issues when I try to update my model:

> ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (64, 2) for Tensor 'action:0',
>   which has shape '(?,)'

So I change the placeholder to provide the action dimension:

```
self.actions = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, 2], 'action')
```

But then the a_indices line throws an error:

> ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 1 and 2
>           From merging shape 0 with other shapes. for 'loss/actor_loss/stack' (op: 'Pack') with input shapes: [?], [?,2].

I guess I need to do some re-shaping of the assignment to a_indices, but to be honest, I'm not sure what that line of code is doing (I'm just piecing together code examples I found on github to try and cater it to what I need).

I'd much most grateful if someone able to assist

Comment: You should not be able to do a `tf.stack` operation with a `tf.int32` and a `tf.float32` tensors. If you fix the data types, the stacking seems alright, though; stacking two vectors of the same "unknown" length would give you a tensor with shape `[None, 2]`. The issue seems to be because you are indeed trying to feed a two-dimensional value to `actions`, which is a one-dimensional tensor. If you change the rank of `actions` then obviously it cannot be stacked with a 1D vector.  Would need to know what exactly you want to get to know what needs fixing.

Comment: "I'm not sure what that line of code is doing" you should probably figure that out first, it may take a bit at the beginning but mashing up code without really understanding it will give you nothing but trouble in the end. Check out [`tf.stack`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack). The line is creating a vector the same size as `actions` ([`tf.shape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape)) with sequential numbers 0, 1, 2, ... ([`tf.range`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/range)), then it's putting that and `actions` as two columns of a 2D tensor.

Comment: @jdehesa sorry, I copy the wrong lines from my code. Both use int32 - I've updated the code.  Yes, I understand what you mean, but equally because I don't fully understand, I don't trust that the solution I come up with is actually correct.  I'm worried I'll just fluke a solution, but it's not actually correct.